# Peaks and dips position in the Planck CMB

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background

I am currently looking for the values of the firsts peaks and dips (at least the first 3) in terms of l and angular size for the CMB angular power spectrum measured from Planck. But the only thing I can find is the plot, not the values.

What are these values ?

Comment: They may not publish those values exactly; I seem to recall that they published the coefficients for the multiple elements. You can reconstruct the location and strength of the peaks and dips from the coefficients. Time to bust out Abramowitz and Stegun or your favorite math methods text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the Planck data from the [LAMBDA Data products pages](http://lambda.gsfc.nasa.gov/product/planck/curr/planck_prod_irsa.cfm) on the NASA web site.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a table with the position and amplitude of the first eight acoustic peaks in page 20 of Planck I: Overview of products https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01582